# DEL saying path doesn't exist (it does)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

I'm guessing this is a basic DOS question, its with the del command.  All I want to do is delete a file.

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\matthewe\Desktop\testfolder>del
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\matthewe\Desktop\testfolder\test.pdf
>   The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

I can guarantee that test.pdf exists, and the fact I've been able to cd to the correct folder shows it exists.  So why the error?

Comment: the superuser exchange might be a better place for this question. issue the exact same command with 'dir' in place of 'del'. if dir can't see it, there must be a misspelling in the filename.

Comment: dir can see it no problem - test.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put your path inside double quote, DOS don't like long path with space inside:

```
del "C:\Documents and Settings\matthewe\Desktop\testfolder\test.pdf"
```

Comment: Ah excellent! Thank you very much.  Now that you've answered I remember doing this in the past - oh well.  Graham also answered correct but I'll give you the points since you have less :-)

Answer (score 2):

use quotes - `del "C:\Documents and Settings\matthewe\Desktop\testfolder\test.pdf"`